# wanting to count the number of weekdays between 2 dates

Tags: mysql, datetime

I am given a start and end date.

i want to count the number of weekdays between those 2 dates.

then in a table of dates, i want to count those in a similar fashion to to pick weekends only.

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to have a materialized table of days / dates.  But this same method, used to build this materialized table, can be used directly in a query.  I show a couple of [weekday] calculations, but you can use the same approach to query about weekend days (weekend day values are 5, and 6):

Direct single query example:

```
SELECT day
     , WEEKDAY(day) AS wkday
  FROM (
SELECT FROM_DAYS(d.day1+v1.result) AS day
  FROM (SELECT TO_DAYS(DATE('2000-01-01')) AS day1
             , TO_DAYS(DATE('2021-01-01')) AS day2
     ) AS d
  JOIN (
      SELECT v1.num+v2.num+v3.num+v4.num AS result
        FROM (
                 SELECT 1 AS num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
           UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
           ) AS v1
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 10 AS num UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40 UNION SELECT 50
           UNION SELECT 60 UNION SELECT 70 UNION SELECT 80 UNION SELECT 90 UNION SELECT 00
           ) AS v2
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 100 AS num UNION SELECT 200 UNION SELECT 300 UNION SELECT 400 UNION SELECT 500
           UNION SELECT 600 UNION SELECT 700 UNION SELECT 800 UNION SELECT 900 UNION SELECT 000
           ) AS v3
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 1000 AS num UNION SELECT 2000 UNION SELECT 3000 UNION SELECT 4000 UNION SELECT 5000
           UNION SELECT 6000 UNION SELECT 7000 UNION SELECT 8000 UNION SELECT 9000 UNION SELECT 0000
           ) AS v4
     ) v1
 WHERE v1.result < (d.day2-d.day1)
     ) AS days
 WHERE WEEKDAY(day) < 5
 LIMIT 10
;



USE test;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS days;

CREATE TABLE days (
   day   date PRIMARY KEY
) ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO days
SELECT FROM_DAYS(d.day1+v1.result)
  FROM (SELECT TO_DAYS(DATE('2000-01-01')) AS day1
             , TO_DAYS(DATE('2021-01-01')) AS day2
     ) AS d
  JOIN (
      SELECT v1.num+v2.num+v3.num+v4.num AS result
        FROM (
                 SELECT 1 AS num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5
           UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
           ) AS v1
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 10 AS num UNION SELECT 20 UNION SELECT 30 UNION SELECT 40 UNION SELECT 50
           UNION SELECT 60 UNION SELECT 70 UNION SELECT 80 UNION SELECT 90 UNION SELECT 00
           ) AS v2
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 100 AS num UNION SELECT 200 UNION SELECT 300 UNION SELECT 400 UNION SELECT 500
           UNION SELECT 600 UNION SELECT 700 UNION SELECT 800 UNION SELECT 900 UNION SELECT 000
           ) AS v3
        JOIN (
                 SELECT 1000 AS num UNION SELECT 2000 UNION SELECT 3000 UNION SELECT 4000 UNION SELECT 5000
           UNION SELECT 6000 UNION SELECT 7000 UNION SELECT 8000 UNION SELECT 9000 UNION SELECT 0000
           ) AS v4
     ) v1
 WHERE v1.result < (d.day2-d.day1)
;

SELECT *
  FROM days
 ORDER BY day
 LIMIT 10
;


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM days;

SELECT MIN(day), MAX(day) FROM days;

SELECT day, WEEKDAY(day) FROM days LIMIT 6;

SELECT day, WEEKDAY(day) AS wkday FROM days WHERE WEEKDAY(day) < 5 LIMIT 6;

SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(day), MAX(day) FROM days WHERE WEEKDAY(day) < 5;
```

Comment: is it possible to do this entirely in a query given 2 dates?  I feel creating a table for this is a bit much.  i know there is a datediff that will get the difference in days of 2 dates, i wasnt sure if there was a way say day minus weekends or something.

Comment: Sure. There are several ways to do this in one query.  You could use the above as a derived table or in a view directly, instead of creating a base table.  Then you could use that derived table or view within your query.  It's very simple.

Comment: Remember, day from that derived table is a date type.  You can simply add a test in the WHERE clause of the outer query for the dates in question:  WHERE day BETWEEN 'somedate' AND 'anotherdate'

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple query to find the number of weekdays within 2 dates with MySql:

```
set @d1='2013-09-25';
set @d2='2013-10-13';

select floor(datediff( @d2, @d1 ) / 7)*5 +
(case  when if(weekday(@d2)>=5,4,weekday(@d2))>=if(weekday(@d1)>=5,4,weekday(@d1)) 
then if(weekday(@d2)>=5,4,weekday(@d2))-if(weekday(@d1)>=5,4,weekday(@d1)) 
else 5+if(weekday(@d2)>=5,4,weekday(@d2))-if(weekday(@d1)>=5,4,weekday(@d1)) end) weekdays;
```

Same algorithm written in PHP:

```
function getWeekDays($d1,$d2){
$d1Array=preg_split('/-/',$d1);
$d2Array=preg_split('/-/',$d2);
$d1w=date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$d1Array[1],$d1Array[2],$d1Array[0]));
$d1w=in_array($d1w,array(0,6))?4:$d1w-1;
$d2w=date('w',mktime(0,0,0,$d2Array[1],$d2Array[2],$d2Array[0]));
$d2w=in_array($d2w,array(0,6))?4:$d2w-1;

$fullWeekDays=floor(((mktime(0,0,0,$d2Array[1],$d2Array[2],$d2Array[0])-mktime(0,0,0,$d1Array[1],$d1Array[2],$d1Array[0]))/86400)/7)*5;
$offset=$d2w>=$d1w?($d2w-$d1w):(5+$d2w-$d1w);
$weekDays=$fullWeekDays+$offset;

return $weekDays;
}
```