# Call Access query and add column for each record returned

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a query that looks like so...

```
SELECT tbl1.ProjectID, tbl1.EntryDate AS StartDate, tbl2.EntryDate AS EndDate
FROM checklist_entries tbl1
INNER JOIN checklist_entries tbl2
ON tbl1.ProjectID = tbl2.ProjectID
WHERE tbl1.ChecklistDay = (SELECT ChecklistDayMin FROM milestone_def WHERE MilestoneDefID = [@milestoneID])
AND tbl2.ChecklistDay = (SELECT ChecklistDayMax FROM milestone_def WHERE MileStoneDefID = [@milestoneID])
```

As you can see, this is a self-joining table that returns me a ProjectID (FK), a StartDate and EndDate, both of which are the EntryDate column in the table. In order to have records returned, I need to pass in an integer value [@milestoneID] which allows the subqueries to return the min and max values needed for the WHERE clause.

Since this query returns two dates, I would like to find out how I could build upon this query and add another column that is returned with an integer value of TotalDays (TotalDays being business days, Mon-Fri) determined from the returned StartDate and EndDate.

I can find a query to return the number of days but basically I would like to create a query in ACCESS that allows me to call this query (and pass in the [@MilestoneID] parameter) and for each record returned, add a column to the end of the TotalDays count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16787954/2144390), you can create a VBA function to include the number of weekdays using

```
SELECT 
    ... ,
    CountWeekdays(tbl1.EntryDate, tbl2.EntryDate) AS TotalWeekdays 
FROM ...
```

Just create a new `Module` in Access and paste the following code into it:

```vbs
Public Function CountWeekdays(Date1 As Date, Date2 As Date) As Long
Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, _
        Weekdays As Long, i As Long
If Date1 > Date2 Then
    StartDate = Date2
    EndDate = Date1
Else
    StartDate = Date1
    EndDate = Date2
End If
Weekdays = 0
For i = 0 To DateDiff("d", StartDate, EndDate)
    Select Case Weekday(DateAdd("d", i, StartDate))
        Case 1, 7
            ' weekend - do nothing
        Case Else
            Weekdays = Weekdays + 1
    End Select
Next
CountWeekdays = Weekdays
End Function
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, but how would I do this using SQL only? This Access database is temporary and will be migrated to MySQL shortly, I'd like to keep the work on the back-end rather than within application code.

Comment: @user1066133 Don't think of the VBA function as "application code", think of it as the Access equivalent to a SQL Server "Scalar-valued Function" or a MySQL "function". To accomplish the same thing in Access SQL alone would be ugly (it would involve a numbers table and several levels of derived tables) and it almost certainly wouldn't translate directly to MySQL. Even a "plain-SQL" solution in MySQL is a bit gnarly, as illustrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12925535/2144390).

Comment: Yeah you're right. Only issue I'm having with this is that when I run the query now it errors with "Undefined function 'CountWeekDays' in expression." The module is clearly named the same and was copied/pasted exactly as shown.

Comment: @user1066133 Verify that the function is in a "regular" VBA Module, not a "Class Module" or the module associated with a Form (which is also a Class Module).

Comment: Clicked on the Create tab, over to the far right I clicked "Module" on top of "Class Module" and pasted in the code and gave it the name 'CountWeekDays'. Pretty sure that's a standard module.

Comment: @user1066133 Perhaps Access is grumpy because the `Module` and the `Function` have the same name.Try leaving the `Function` name as-is and renaming the `Module` to 'modCountWeekdays'. (Way-back-when, Access used to get confused by duplicate names so I just got into the habit of prefixing Module names with 'mod'.)

Comment: Coming back to this today, when I run the query in Access, it works fine. When I create a Command Object and set the CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure and call set the CommandText to the query name and attempt to fill a DataTable, I get the same error of "Undefined function 'CountWeekDays' in expression... :(

Comment: @user1066133 I see you've started another question to address this.